# Адаптив во Vue3 использую tailwindcss

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, nuxt.js, vue3, tailwindcss

```html
<div
    class="justify-between"
    :style="[ mainStore.getCollapsed ? 'width: 93vw' : 'width: 83vw']"
  >
<div/>
```

[image: ****]
Всем привет,такой вопрос. Необходимо сделать адаптив страницы. В проекте используется библиотека tailwindcss, проект сам на vue 3. В inline стилях прописаны ширина при открытии и закрытии страницы. Прописывал адаптив в классах, но не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста где необходимо прописать адаптив?

Comment: вам ответ тоже в виде скриншота выкладывать?

Comment: Ой, извините. Новичок здесь, необходимо код приложить?

Comment: да, ведь с картинки вообще неудобно смотреть

Comment: Добавил код как вы и сказали

Comment: Скобки квадратные уберите.

Comment: Не помогло к сожалению

Answer (score 0):

нужно немного переделать: **сперва свойство а потом условие**, пример для наглядности

```js
const color = {
  data() {
    return {
      isActiv: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    btnClickColor() {
      this.isActiv = !this.isActiv
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(color).mount('#color')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>


<div id="color">
  <p :style="{color: isActiv ? 'red' : 'green' }">Очень красивый текст</p>
  <button @click="btnClickColor">Изменить цвет</button>
</div>
```